Acidity of toluene compared to propyne
Why is propyne more acidic than toluene? The carbanion formed in case of toluene is easily stabilised by resonance and -I effect of toluene. In case of propyne there is an electron donating methylgroup present which would destabilises the anion formed. The explanation I found was that propyne consists of sp carbon which is mroe electronegative. However can we really weigh that against factors like resonance?

You're comparing apples with oranges.

Well you see this question was present in my organic practice questions, cant help it

It is to do with the sp carbon, but just citing electronegativity is insufficient. The propyne anion formed from deprotonation is anionic on an sp carbon and hence has a HOMO lone pair in an sp orbital.
In the case of toluene all the feasible resonance forms of the anion lead to sp2 carboanions with a lone pair in a much higher energy sp3 orbital.
Hence the conjugate base of toluene has a higher HOMO, is less stable and so toluene is a weaker acid.

It's sp2 in toluene.

In toluene, the "lone pair" is more likely in a p orbital, which is in conjugation with the aromatic system. It is definitely not in an sp³ orbital.
